# How sort a zipped dictionary with a tupled list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary with items as tuples with two elements in it: id and seconds (this last one is inside a list).

I want to order it, in such a way that if there is any tuple that has a list with more than one element, separate it along with its id, according to an order in seconds (from least to greatest), as the example shows

**Code:**

```py
dictionary.items()

dict_items(
            [
            ('268 084 071', [36900]), 
            ('582 992 529', [43200]), 
            ('627 335 2770', [50400, 322800]), # tuple with id and a list of seconds
            ('171-451-814', [116600]), 
            ('537 430 002', [310200]), 
            ('366 342 588', [380900]), 
            ('994-4098-8201', [387200]), 
            ('981-2739-3075', [396200])
            ]
          )
```

---

Expected output: dictionary to a ordered list, from smallest to largest in seconds, and separating the elements of the list with more than one element and grouping each element with its id

```
    [
        ('268 084 071', [36900]), 
        ('582 992 529', [43200]), 
        ('627 335 2770', [50400]), # was separated 
        ('171-451-814', [116600]), 
        ('537 430 002', [310200]), 
        ('627 335 2770', [322800]), # in here
        ('366 342 588', [380900]), 
        ('994-4098-8201', [387200]), 
        ('981-2739-3075', [396200])
    ]
```

Comment: Dictionary keys are unique, so you can't separate them and use the same key.  You can do it if you store the result in a list of two-tuples.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, I know. That's right, that is what I want. But my problem start with a dictionary of tuples and the tuples with one list and one element (the id).

Comment: A dictionary is unordered. So I am not sure what you want to do with the ordering.

Comment: Maybe extract the data and ordering it into a list. Im getting this data from a csv converted to a dictionary.

Comment: @Sri Python `dict` maintains insertion order in CPython 3.6 as an implementation detail, and was guaranteed in Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want with a dictionary due to the duplicate keys, but this creates a list with the separated data:

```
d = dict([('268 084 071', [36900]), 
          ('582 992 529', [43200]), 
          ('627 335 2770', [50400, 322800]), # tuple with id and a list of seconds
          ('171-451-814', [116600]), 
          ('537 430 002', [310200]), 
          ('366 342 588', [380900]), 
          ('994-4098-8201', [387200]), 
          ('981-2739-3075', [396200])])

lst = []
for key,values in d.items():
    for value in values:  # make values separate entries in the list
        lst.append((key,value))

lst.sort(key=lambda x:x[1]) # re-sort by value when done

for item in lst:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
('268 084 071', 36900)
('582 992 529', 43200)
('627 335 2770', 50400)
('171-451-814', 116600)
('537 430 002', 310200)
('627 335 2770', 322800)
('366 342 588', 380900)
('994-4098-8201', 387200)
('981-2739-3075', 396200)
```

Comment: I was not looking for get the same dictionary as the output, this list is what I was looking. Thank you.